# How to format cell correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, constraints

I'm trying to match the layout and presentation of info in a collection cell, to a collection cell mockup I have(the one with the red markups). I've attached the cell I currently have which has the title of an article and image parsed. The title and image should be right next to each other on the same horizontal line. Instead the title sits above the image. How can i modify this so the title and image are side by side?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHYHW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YprhU.png)

// Setup for news cell. Add view components and create
    // their layouts.

```
override func setupViews() {
    addSubview(background)
    addSubview(title)
    addSubview(image)
    addSubview(articleDescription)

    // Horizontal Auto layout for views
    constrain(visualFormat: "|[v0]|", view: ["v0": background])
    constrain(visualFormat: "V:|-1-[v0]-1-|", view: ["v0": background])
    constrain(visualFormat: "|-200-[v0]|", view: ["v0": title])
    constrain(visualFormat: "|-50-[v0]-200-|", view: ["v0": image])
    constrain(visualFormat: "|[v0]|", view: ["v0": articleDescription])
    constrain(visualFormat: "|[v0]|", view: ["v0": background])
    constrain(visualFormat: "|[v0]|", view: ["v0": background])

    // Vertical autolayout for views.
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-50-[v0(20)][v1(144)][v2(42)]-8-|",
        options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(),
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["v0": title, "v1": image,
                "v2": articleDescription]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Auto Layout Programmatically everything will be easier.
You should watch this video to understand how to control the subview, using layout anchor... that’s enough.
https://youtu.be/9RydRg0ZKaI